# Disappearing question

Tags: support

I answered [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1869994/tabitem-header-text-multibinding) this morning, and I just noticed it [asked again](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1870564/need-help-with-tabcontrol-itemtemplate), but the old one has disappeared? why?

Body of original question from browser cache:

> Hello.
>
> How do I set the TabItem.Header to
>   bindings taken from few fields, each
>   binding shown in a different size, all
>   in the place of the original header
>   text; without overriding the default
>   style and behavior of the header - I
>   only need the text.
>
> I tried to set its template but then
>   it creates a rectangle that contains
>   the inner controls, and this rectengle
>   is not responsive for user clicks, and
>   also have the control-style, i want
>   this controls to be unvisible, only
>   its text should be visible.
>
> I've tried the following:
>
> But it doesn't show anything.
>
> I've also tried to set the
>   HeaderTemplate to a DataTemplate but
>   what happens is, the DataTemplate
>   overrides the TabItem style and when I
>   click the text it doesn't go to the
>   clicked tab, besides, the unselected
>   tabs look very funny, I see the
>   rectengle of the text floating, while
>   I want it to be transparent.
>
> So, to summarize up my question, I
>   want to set TabItem.Header.Text to a
>   MultiBinding with StringFormat.
>
> Any idea would be really appreciated.
>   Thanks.

Agreed the question has been changed, but why not just change the question if he asked it wrong/badly?

It was very dajavu to find the question again but without my answer present.

Comment: In fact another user had given an answer the was the same as the accepted answer on the new question.

Comment: Just had the same thing happen to me with a question regarding jQuery Droppable this morning.  

Its really annoying that people can just delete questions after you go to the trouble of providing them with a working code sample in your answer.

Answer (score 4):

The author deleted it, that's why it's gone.

Comment: Seems like a rep heist gone wrong to me.

Comment: Well that was obvious. I guess my question was more a META level, what's the opinion about this happening. Do the powers that be love it, like it, dislike it, discourage it. Is there anything done about it. Just trying to workout the correct level of whining. But on the whole it's annoying to have my answer deleted, as I find them usefull snippest of code.

Comment: This happened to me today... if the author deleted it and I'm in the middle of answering the question/updating an answer I already posted, I would like a notification or something. It's not fun to find out I just wasted my last 15 minutes.